# window.confirm take the cancel button out

Tags: javascript, html

How do I take the cancel Button from the window.confirm??
Is there a way to taking it out and only the OK button will show up?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't want a cancel button, you might as well just use `alert()`:

```
alert('This operation is not possible');
```

In beautiful ascii art it looks like this:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|                                   |
|  This operation is not possible   |
|                                   |
|            +--------+             |
|            |   OK   |             |
|            +--------+             |
+-----------------------------------+
```

When either OK is clicked or the dialog is dismissed, the next statement in your code will be executed.

If the next statement should be conditional, you'd have to stick with `confirm()` unfortunately.

Comment: How can I program the ok button so when I clicked it ,it will go to the other page

Comment: @user2242573 The next statement will run once OK (or dialog close button) is clicked; if you want this action to be cancelable you have to stick with `confirm()` though.

Comment: @Ja͢ck did you ever see that alert doesn't block the program and the program executes next statement?

Comment: @YuAnShaolinMaculelêLai i suppose `alert()` could be overridden with another implementation, not sure

Answer (score 1):

`window.alert` is what you want.

Or simply `alert`, just like `window.confirm` can be `confirm`(unless you hide those with variables with those names.

Comment: how to i program the ok in alert ? same as the window.confirm?

Comment: @user2242573, `alert("message")`

Comment: I mean when I click the ok it will go to the other page

Comment: @user2242573, `alert("message"); window.location = "newURL";`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the `alert`. Following is an example:

#### HTML

```
<button id="test"> Go To Another Page</button>
<br><br>
<iframe src='http://www.example.com' height="400px" width="100%" id="page"></iframe>
```

#### jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#test').click(function(){
        var page = $('iframe');
        alert("You'll be redirected to a new page now");
        page.attr('src', 'http://www.monkeyman.com'); // This line is executed once you hit ok on the alert.
    });
});
```

Here is a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GvqyD/). I had to use an iframe because of jsfiddle. In your scenario you may want to remove the iframe thing and simply change:

`page.attr('src', 'http://www.monkeyman.com');`

to

`window.location('http://www.monkeyman.com');`